# Video not playing in fullscreen?

Tags: android-video-player

I am using a videoplayer in my app.I want the video to be played in fullscreen and in landscape mode.I have done for landscape but for fullscreen, i have tried android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen  in manifest also but its not working.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the methods for Fullscreen but nothing is working.So,this might be the problem with the video size because in normal player also video is not playing in fullscreen.If anybody is having updates pls share it.

After digging some time,i got to know that video size is the problem.If it is larger in size its coming in fullscreen.